# How can I make a button which swaps between 3 background colors?

Tags: c#, windows, if-statement, nested-if

So I'm trying to figure out how to have the click of a button swap between 3 background colors in a windows application form. Managed to make it swap between 2, but struggling to move up to three.

The result of ~30 minutes of trying everything that came to mind: https://prnt.sc/1rka67i

The 2 color variation: https://prnt.sc/1rkakrm

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the code

Comment: edit: added an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could modify property of Form's backgroud on button click event like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.White; //for example 
}
```

If you want to swap between 3 colors you could try like:

```
int counter = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    if(counter == 1)
        this.BackColor = Color.White; //for example 
    if(counter == 2)
        this.BackColor = Color.Black; //for example 
    if(counter == 3){
        this.BackColor = Color.Gray; //for example 
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```